# Why Oracle SQL Developer is so slow when open a big script?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a script which has more than 15,000 lines. it will take around 90 seconds to open in Oracle SQL Developer. But when opening it in DBeaver or Navicat, it can be opened immediately. why is this happening? How to solve? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably parsing the input. If you execute the `jstack` command a couple of times and see `oracle.dbtools.arbori` or `oracle.dbtools.parser` in the call stack, then that's probably what's going on. The parser has improved in version 20.2.

Comment: what @JeffHolt said is abs correct - we do a lot of stuff to your code to make the GUI provide all those nice features. You can disable some of those, try unchecking the 'Supported' options in Preferences - Code Editor. And also, yes, make sure you're on a recent copy as we have made some performance improvements over the years.

Comment: What time it takes if you *run* the script? I suspect much more that the parsing time...

Comment: Hi Jeff and Thatjeffsmith, I have unchecked the 4 'Supported' options in Preferences-Code Editor, but it is still as slow as before.

Comment: Hi Marmite, it only take me about 1 minute to run this script, i.e. the time to open it is almost same or even longer than it runs

Comment: What's worse, I can not do anything else in SQL Developer until this script is open, it is frozen there

Comment: And the version of SQL Developer I am using is V20.2.0.175

Comment: Look for sqldeveloper.sh in the application. In it, there are ways to run it in debugging mode where the debugging log shows up in a new docked window. Don't forget to look at the call stack. The call stack for at least one of the threads will be a good data source to help diagnose the problem. Additionally, the parser isn't perfect. I've found examples that make it go crazy taking hundreds of seconds to complete.

Comment: Without your script I couldn't guess...it might help to add memory to the JVM, but I'm guessing we're burning CPU

Comment: If you're just running it, don't even open it. Run via @script.sql/F5